# How to read outgoing/sent emails from mailbox?

Tags: c#, .net, email, pop3

Is there any method in .NET to read the outgoing/sent messages from a mailbox?
I've accessed the received messages through Pop3.NET library, but I don't get how to access the sent messages.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the mail server supports the IMAP protocol, you can use a library such as [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) to access the "Sent" folder, but whether the message(s) you expect to be there are there or not will all depend on whether the client that sent the message(s) also appended them (via IMAP or otherwise) to the "Sent" foolder.

FOr example, if you are sending mail using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient, then any message(s) you send with that API will *NOT* end up in the account's "Sent" folder unless you explicitly append the message to that folder using a library such as MailKit to do it.